# run bb10 sample app on ripple emulator (mac os x)

Tags: ripple, blackberry-10

I followed the instruction at:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/use_the_ripple_emulator_chrome_extension_2007542_11.html

to run remote site app project, it works.
But when I tested sample (bbui.js sample) on local disk

BB10 document said:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/accessing_a_local_project_in_ripple_1948645_11.html

So I copied the bbuijs samples project to
Mac OS: /Users//RippleSites.samples

But when I pointed chrome to
localhost:9910/samples/index.htm      (Ripple emulator extension)

[image]

Chrome said
could not connect to localhost:9910

[image]

Is there anything wrong?

Do I need to run web server sharing?

[image]

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest thing to do here it got to enable "web sharing" (your last pic). create a symbolic link from the Web Server's home dir to your samples. So:

```
cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/
ln -s <path to your samples> <name of dir>
```

Note: you might have to use "sudo" ahead of that last command.

You should then be able to go to 127.0.0.1/(name of dir) and it should work for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem ("could not connect to localhost:9910") on Windows 7 in Chrome with Ripple emulator version 0.9.10 (beta)

The documentation at https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/accessing_a_local_project_in_ripple_1948645_11.html
does mention how to install the Chrome extention. But it does not mention that the Ripple button in Chrome has a popup where you can start the local service running on port 9910.

My steps taken were:

- Open the kitchensink example by following https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/enabling_the_ripple_emulator.html
- This allows you to see the Ripple emulator working.
- Create the local directory as described in https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/accessing_a_local_project_in_ripple_1948645_11.html
- Then you will be able to see the services button and start the service.
- Open your local project via loaclhost:9910/

Image of the option menu:

[image: Start stop services]
<sub>(source: [escay.nl](http://escay.nl/stackoverflow/RippleServices.png))</sub>